# Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception.

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm trying to test this method, however I am getting the following error:

```
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception.
```

On this line of 
Code:

```
    when(tester.method(
            any(String.class), any(LocalDate.class), any(boolean.class),any(boolean.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(item);
```

Comment: Could you post more of your test code? Specifically around the mocking of tester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already built-in matchers for most of the types you are using.

```
when(tester.method(anyString(), any(LocalDate.class), anyBoolean(),anyBoolean(), anyString()))
.thenReturn(item);
```

Reference [Class ArgumentMatchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.20.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html)

> For primitive types use `any{Type}()` family.

Comment: Since Mockito 2.1.0, anyChar() only works on character primitives

Comment: @dementis I took the quote straight from documentation. I could understand the confusion. updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you shouldn't be using `boolean.class`, since lower case boolean is a primitive, and doesn't return a java.lang object.
Use `Boolean.class`, or `anyBoolean()`